# Oozie Re-run the workflow from the node, where it was last killed

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I am using the MR action in oozie. And want to use the suspend/resume functionality provided by oozie on MR.

The problem - However, when we call 'suspend' on Oozie that doesn't kill the hadoop job instead it only updates the oozie state, while the hadoop job continues to run to completion. I want the hadoop job to be killed immediately when the oozie workflow is suspended. Guess that's not possible right ?

So, I figured I can kill the oozie workflow and re-run it. 
But now the problem is , if there are 3 action nodes in my workflow, I don't want to re-run all of them.

Am I smoking here or is it possible to access the last successful oozie node ( which is most likely stored in the mysql database) ?

Is there a better approach to my connived use-case ?

Appreciate your help in advance,

P.S. I am not posting my workflow because it's a simple workflow with several map-reduce actions, no rocket science here.

Answer (score 2):

The oozie command line interface allows for the flag "-rerun" to be used in the following context:

```
oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -config job.properties -rerun 14-20090525161321-oozie-joe
```

There is one issue in the automation of reruns, and this is that you must supply a list of action nodes to skip inside of the job.properties file using the oozie.wf.rerun.skip.nodes variable.
This following is taken from [source](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/DG_CommandLineTool.html#Job_Operations)

> Only one of following two configurations is mandatory. Both should not be defined at the same time
>   oozie.wf.rerun.skip.nodes
>   oozie.wf.rerun.failnodes
>   Skip nodes are comma separated list of action names. They can be any action nodes including decision node.
>   The valid value of oozie.wf.rerun.failnodes is true or false.
>   If secured hadoop version is used, the following two properties needs to be specified as well
>   mapreduce.jobtracker.kerberos.principal
>   dfs.namenode.kerberos.principal.

In order to get the automation, it might be worth you time to try appending to the properties file on completion of an action using either a shell script or implementing it directly into your MR jobs.